# AWS EC2 Linux - GRUB with password

Tags: amazon-ec2

Any idea if it is possible to set password for the GRUB bootloader? If set then how it is possible to enter password? What happen when auto scale without human entering password?

Answer (score 5):

AWS does not provide "console access" to EC2 instances, so you can set a GRUB password the usual way, but you will not be able to enter it at boot. Your instance will become inaccessible after reboot.

If you absolutely need GRUB password (but why?) the only option is to look at other providers that allow use console (DigitalOcean, for example).

Comment: hi, thanks for the info, basically my security team complaining the GRUB need password due to security reason and we are arguing with them with the same reason above.

Comment: I'm also getting this request from my security review team and I had to forward them to this question because they would not believe that this was a dumb request for an AWS EC2 instance.

Comment: I happen came across the same issue from the security team, This is actually unnecessary to set bootloader password in EC2!

Answer (score 1):

Setting a bootloader password prevents the command line boot parameters from being changed without the user providing the bootloader password. Booting the system in single user mode would therefore require the bootloader password, as single user mode requires modification of the boot entries.

You can add --unrestricted to the menu entries to allow the system to boot without
entering a password. This does away with the need to enter the bootloader password when rebooting systems (or launching new EC2 instances through an Auto Scaling Group and your custom AMI). Password will still be required to edit menu items. This primarily protects against AWS staff who may be able to get access to instance boot disks on EBS.

Comment: But what if you have encrypted root volume? will aws staff able gain access?

Comment: That is a completely separate question of course but I would say no, not unless AWS staff are able to compromise the data key for the disk. If they do get access to the data key and are able to mount the decrypted disk, setting the bootloader password with the "--unrestricted" option would still prevent them from booting the system in single user mode. I am not recommending it as a practice of course, merely stating what is possible and its impact.